# search query associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am implementing groups feature. I am stuck at searching members of a group.
Let say

```
Class Group
  has_many :group_memberships  
  has_many :members, :source => :user, :through => :group_memberships
end

Class GroupMembership
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end

Class User
  has_many :group_memberships  
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_memberships
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
end

Class Profile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How to search group members, with searchable fields in profile

Comment: And the question is...?

Answer (score 1):

Could something like below work for you?

```
group = Group.find(id)
users = group.users.joins(:profiles).where("profile.age>18")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of eager loading -
just Specify Condition on Eager Loaded Associations like -

```
group = Group.last

users = group.users.includes(:profiles).where("profiles.name" => "xyz")
```

For more details refer - 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations